# I need to add default value as currentdate + 10days

Tags: sql, postgresql

When a row is inserted,

I need to insert a default value `(current date + 10days)` in a column

(eg ) today is "2018-02-07" then it should enter as default value "2018-02-16"

Answer (score 0):

Based on ..

```
CREATE TABLE t (d DATE);
```

This is the statement

```
INSERT INTO t (d) VALUES (CURRENT_DATE + 10);
```

Answer (score 0):

just set with `ALTER COLUMN column_name SET DEFAULT current_date + '10 days'::interval;`

smth like:

```
t=# alter table so3 alter COLUMN t set default current_date + '10 days'::interval;
ALTER TABLE
t=# \d so3
                         Table "public.so3"
 Column | Type |                      Modifiers
--------+------+-----------------------------------------------------
 t      | date | default (('now'::text)::date + '10 days'::interval)
```